Older SSIS Project wouldn’t open in Data Tools- Protection Level mismatch
I ran into an ssis work around I thought I'd share. We had an ssis package created in Data Tools 2015, and it was in Prod and running daily and untouched since 2017. We are migrating to SQL Server 2022 plus new servers and while prepping for testing found that this particular ssis project would not open for any reason, giving error: 'MS Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working'.
My question: is there a better way to identify the ssis 'ProtectionLevel' values mismatching between the XML settings at the 'project level' compared to the 'ProtectionLevel' for each ssis package?
I'm sorry I can't simply place a code sample here for others to easily run a test, and I'm looking for a reply from someone experienced with older ssis pkgs. I believe this is an issue where the pre-2017 ssis editor (Data Tools) left settings within the .dtproj file that are now conflicting with the new ssis editor and preventing data tools from opening this project.
Short answer: I manually changed the xml values for 'protection level' in the .dtproj file (using text editor) to 'dont save sensitive', and the ssis package protection level from a value of 1 to 0 on all pkgs, and I was then able to open the project with Data Tools. I'm questioning validity of my workaround/hack here.
More wordy explanation....
One thing that led me to this work around was that in testing, I created a new temp project and re-added the packages from the original project to it, and right clicked the project to do a "Build". This particular ssis package executes at least a dozen other packages within it so once I added all of those missing components to the temp project, then I was able to run the package from data tools. Prior to doing the Build it did complain that the protection level mismatched between the project and packages, so I changed project properties and each package properties to 'dont save sensitive'….
There was many other components within the original project, and I wanted to keep that project intact. I opened the original .dtproj file in text editor and as soon as I manually updated the 'protection level' values shown in my code block below, then finally Data Tools stopped crashing and the project would open and the package would run without issue. With my workaround I was able to retain the original project and redeploy everything in the project to the new servers without issue. I'm posting this issue in the hopes it might help someone.
here is a portion of the .dtproj file for your review:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DeploymentModel>Project</DeploymentModel>
  <ProductVersion>14.0.600.250</ProductVersion>
  <SchemaVersion>9.0.1.0</SchemaVersion>
  <State>$base64$PFNvdXJjZUNvb.......F</State>
  <Database>
    <Name>Collections Data Import.database</Name>
    <FullPath>Collections Data Import.database</FullPath>
  </Database>
  <DataSources />
  <DataSourceViews />
  <DeploymentModelSpecificContent>
    <Manifest>

      <SSIS:Project SSIS:ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive" xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">

...

        <SSIS:DeploymentInfo>
          <SSIS:ProjectConnectionParameters />
          <SSIS:PackageInfo>
            <SSIS:PackageMetaData SSIS:Name="Agent Staging.dtsx">
              <SSIS:Properties>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ID">{7EA6AFCB-3303-4871-84CA-94E2CC1CCBA5}</SSIS:Property>

...
                </SSIS:Property>

                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ProtectionLevel">0</SSIS:Property>

              </SSIS:Properties>

values before my changes:
<SSIS:Project SSIS:ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" 
<SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ProtectionLevel"\>1\</SSIS:Property\>

Windows event viewer showed the following app errors, for Data Tools crashing (but didn't really help me debug this---included for future searches):
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)

plus this one:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.21615, time stamp: 0x64ffee7f
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0002dfd8
Faulting process id: 0x11bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01dac199ca39ac14
Faulting application path: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\KERNELBASE.dll

Windows event viewer was not much help, finding the reason why Data Tools would not start.

If you can get to the properties window for the package there is an option for Security and then Protection Level.  Right click on the package in the solution and bring up properties and you should be able to edit it there.

Cannot even get Data Tools to open so no way to do that... but thanks for the reply.
